# Textarea default value

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have been using the following to put a default value in a textfield

```
<textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="5" value="Comment"
    class="form_text text-input shadow" title="Comment"
    onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Comment';}" 
    onfocus="if (this.value == 'Comment') {this.value = '';}">
</textarea>
```

and it partially works. The field doesn't show a default value initially but if you click inside it and then out, without typing anything, it displays "Comment".

Any idea how I can modify this so that "Comment" appears when form loads.

Comment: I should add that the same code works fine for a textfield.

Comment: Some interesting answers. Thanks y'all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Textarea default text must be enclosed in tags

```
<textarea> this is my default text </textarea>
```

Comment: yes it works with `<input type="text"> value </input>` as well but input box has a value field, textarea does not. Also be aware of a single space. `<texarea> space on left</textarea>`, not you will actually see a space on left in the default text.

Answer (score 3):

```
<textarea>default value</textarea>
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Dont use value use:

```
<textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="5"
    class="form_text text-input shadow" title="Comment"
    onblur="if (this.innerHTML == '') {this.innerHTML = 'Comment';}" 
    onfocus="if (this.innerHTML == 'Comment') {this.innerHTML = '';}">
Comment
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

textarea has innerHTML not value attribute.(value="Comment" is not correct way to set value)

Try,

```
<textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="5" 
   class="form_text text-input shadow" title="Comment"  
   onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Comment';}" 
   onfocus="if (this.value == 'Comment') {this.value = '';}">
   Comment
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `<textarea>` element has no `value` attribute : the default value is what you write between the open and the close tags:

```
<textarea>My default value</textarea>
```

In Javascript, you can acces this text with `.innerHTML` (or using jQuery with `.val()`).

For the behavior you are trying to realize, you can use [HTML5 placeholder attribute](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder) and use a [jQuery polyfill for old browsers](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder).

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea>Value</textarea>
```

Alternatively, you could assign the value through javascript on load if you used $(document).ready() via jquery.